# Java JCombobox causes rendering problems

Tags: java, swing, combobox, render

Hello, I have the following problem:

```
public class TestCombo extends JFrame{

    public TestCombo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200,200);
        setVisible(true);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4));

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("test1");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("test2");

        panel.add(l1);
        panel.add(l2);

//      JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();// <-- uncomment this for the problem

        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCombo();
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am doing a very simple example. If I uncomment the marked part, the label items are not shown. If I resize the window, they are visible again. The strange thing here is that I do not even add the `combo` to the panel or anywhere. I am just instantiating it. 
Can someone tell me why I need to resize the frame to see the labels? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are doing `setVisible(true)` in the very beginning.

You should do it after adding all components.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is valid syntax for JComboBox

```
JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();
```

it should be

```
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
```

---

Also `setVisible(true);` should be after `this.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);`.

---

[How to use comboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: My Eclipse says it is valid :). As far as i know you can use a generic combobox

Comment: @Aleks: Strange. It is not valid for eclipse at my side. May be you are using different java configuration for compiling classes.

Comment: I think JComboBox became generic with java7

Comment: That might be it. I am using java 7